# Mysterious green lines in space

Tags: eve-online

I was travelling and this caught my eye (click to enlarge):

[image: Mysterious green lines in space]

Notice the strange green line connecting two bright stars left of the overview. What is its purpose? My uneducated guess is that it has something to do with cynosural fields or jump bridges, but it could also just be eye candy or a bug, either way I am having difficulties finding out about it on Google.

Does anyone know what it means? Sometimes I see whole networks of them, though evidently when I went to find a specimen to screenshot they all disappeared and I could only find this one in Rens.

I'm sure it's not a groundbreaking discovery but I'm just curious to know :p

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The lines are an in-game depiction of your autopilot route, they were added with the retribution 1.1 update.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are these accurate depiction of the relative location of systems?